# NetworkWriter WriteBytes: buffer is too large

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, buffer

I'm trying to prototype a piece of networking for a coloring book type application I'm developing that allows users to create an image and then send that image to a server that then takes the image and wraps it around an instantiated mesh. My initial problem in this iteration is buffer size. I'm getting the error:

```
NetworkWriter WriteBytes: buffer is too large (699064) bytes. The maximum buffer size is 64K bytes.
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkWriter:WriteBytesFull(Byte[])
TextureMessage:Serialize(NetworkWriter)
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkServer:SendToAll(Int16, MessageBase)
Server:SendTexture(Texture2D, String) (at Assets/Scripts/Server.cs:32)
Server:SendOnButtonPress() (at Assets/Scripts/Server.cs:19)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

How do I increase buffer size? My images will be in the 1.5-2mb range. My code so far is as follows:

```
public class MyMsgType
{
    public static short texture = MsgType.Highest + 1;
}

public class TextureMessage : MessageBase
{
    public byte[] textureBytes;
    public string message; //Optional
}
```

Server-side code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Server : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture2D textureToSend;
    string messageToSend = "Test Message";

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost();
        Debug.Log("Server Started.");
    }

    public void SendOnButtonPress()
    {
        SendTexture(textureToSend, messageToSend);
    }

    //Call to send the Texture and a simple string message
    public void SendTexture(Texture2D texture, string message)
    {
        TextureMessage msg = new TextureMessage();

        //Convert Texture2D to byte array

        msg.textureBytes = texture.GetRawTextureData();
        msg.message = message;

        NetworkServer.SendToAll(MyMsgType.texture, msg);
    }
}
```

Client-side code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Client : MonoBehaviour
{
    NetworkClient myClient;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        NetworkManager.singleton.StartClient();
        Debug.Log("Client Started.");

        setupClient();
    }

    // Create a client and connect to the server port
    public void setupClient()
    {
        //Create new client
        myClient = new NetworkClient();
        //Register to connect event
        myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);
        //Register to texture receive event
        myClient.RegisterHandler(MyMsgType.texture, OnTextureReceive);

        //Connect to server
        myClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 4444);
    }

    //Called when texture is received
    public void OnTextureReceive(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        TextureMessage msg = netMsg.ReadMessage<TextureMessage>();

        //Your Received message
        string message = msg.message;
        Debug.Log("Texture Messsage " + message);

        //Your Received Texture2D
        Texture2D receivedtexture = new Texture2D(4, 4);
        receivedtexture.LoadRawTextureData(msg.textureBytes);
        receivedtexture.Apply();
    }

    public void OnConnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected to server");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a custom config via setting [NetworkManager.connectionConfig](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager-connectionConfig.html) to a [ConnectionConfig](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.ConnectionConfig.PacketSize.html) object that you have set up to have a larger packet size.  The sample code should get you started:

```
void Start()
{
    ConnectionConfig myConfig = new ConnectionConfig();
    myConfig.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
    myConfig.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableFragmented);
    myConfig.PacketSize = 1440;
    NetworkManager.connectionConfig = myConfig;
}
```

Comment: Where do I say which channel type to use when I actually send the message?

Comment: connectionConfig is a read-only property. this doesn't seem to work at the moment.

Comment: @greyBow The documentation doesn't say that it is read only. I have never used it, so all I have is the documentation.

Comment: The is the error I'm getting: `Assets/Scripts/Server.cs(31,10): error CS0200: Property or indexer `UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkManager.connectionConfig' cannot be assigned to (it is read-only)`

Comment: @greyBow What version of Unity are you using?