# Buffer is too large error despite assigning ReliableFragmented channel to Network Manager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-unet

I'm having trouble with sending an image file that's around 1.5 mb across my network. I have configured NetworkManager to use QoSType ReliableFragmented,  but it's apparently not working. What am I doing wrong? Code and screenshot of NetworkManager component attached.

The error I'm receving is:

```
NetworkWriter WriteBytes: buffer is too large (1699064) bytes. The maximum buffer size is 64K bytes.
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkWriter:WriteBytesFull(Byte[])
TextureMessage:Serialize(NetworkWriter)
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkServer:SendToAll(Int16, MessageBase)
Server:SendTexture(Texture2D, String) (at Assets/Scripts/Server.cs:41)
Server:SendOnButtonPress() (at Assets/Scripts/Server.cs:28)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

Code to start network and serialize data

TextureMessage.cs

```
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class TextureMessage : MessageBase
{
    public byte[] textureBytes;
    public string message; //Optional
}
```

MyMsgType.cs

```
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class MyMsgType
{
    public static short texture = MsgType.Highest + 1;
}
```

Server.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Server : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture2D textureToSend;
    string messageToSend = "Test Message";

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost();
        Debug.Log("Server Started.");
    }

    public void SendOnButtonPress()
    {
        SendTexture(textureToSend, messageToSend);
    }

    //Call to send the Texture and a simple string message
    public void SendTexture(Texture2D texture, string message)
    {
        TextureMessage msg = new TextureMessage();

        //Convert Texture2D to byte array

        msg.textureBytes = texture.GetRawTextureData();
        msg.message = message;

        NetworkServer.SendToAll(MyMsgType.texture, msg);
    }
}
```

[image: Network Manager Component]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetworkWriter WriteBytes: buffer is too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802301/networkwriter-writebytes-buffer-is-too-large)

Answer (score 0):

How it works internal.

NetworkServer.SendToAll():

```
static public bool SendToAll(short msgType, MessageBase msg)
{
    if (LogFilter.logDev) { Debug.Log("Server.SendToAll msgType:" + msgType); }
    bool result = true;

    // this list holds all connections (local and remote)
    for (int i = 0; i < connections.Count; i++)
    {
        NetworkConnection conn = connections[i];
        if (conn != null)
            result &= conn.Send(msgType, msg);
    }

    return result;
}
```

NetworkConnection public constructor:

```
public NetworkConnection()
{
    m_Writer = new NetworkWriter();
}
```

NetworkConnection.Send():

```
public virtual bool Send(short msgType, MessageBase msg)
{
    return SendByChannel(msgType, msg, Channels.DefaultReliable);
}
```

NetworkConnection.SendByChannel():

```
public virtual bool SendByChannel(short msgType, MessageBase msg, int channelId)
{
    m_Writer.StartMessage(msgType);
    msg.Serialize(m_Writer);
    m_Writer.FinishMessage();
    return SendWriter(m_Writer, channelId);
}
```

As you see, it use NetworkWriter to serialize your message. NetworkWriter have buffer with size of 64Kb. You can't serialize object larger than 64K. So you have at least two solutions:

1. Fragment your texture to array/list of blocks lesser than 64K, and send it coherently, step by step.
2. Rewrite all networking code.